# How to build a layout separated to 3 parts

Tags: android, layout, textview

I want to create a `layout` (doesn't matter which one) that separated to 3 parts, and the 2 outter parts (left & right) will include a `TextView`. Like this:
[image]

How exactly do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to do your own adjustments in the code below.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:maxWidth="130dp"        
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider1"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:background="#00BDFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:maxLength="8"        
        android:maxWidth="65dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider2"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="#00BDFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text3"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"                
        android:maxLength="8"
        android:maxWidth="70dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **this**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
    />
    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider1"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#f00" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
    />
    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider2"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#f00
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```